# Report the depth and number of leaves of the learned tree of DecisionTreeClassifier in scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-tree

How to extract the depth and number of leaves of the learned tree of DecisionTreeClassifier in scikit-learn?

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depth of learned tree and number of leaves can be extracted using `clf.get_depth()` and `clf.get_n_leaves()` functions respectively.